# Angular momentum operators for representation of su(2)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, mathematical-physics

How to calculate $J_z$ and $exp(itJ_z)$ for irreducible representation of $su(2)$ with $j=\frac{5}{2}$, expressing it as $n\times n$ matrices?

I know that $J_z|j,m\rangle=m|j,m\rangle$, and $m=-j, -j+1,...,j$, so I tried writing $J_z$ for every $m$ like that:

$J_z|\frac{5}{2},-\frac{5}{2}\rangle=-\frac{5}{2}(0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1)^T$

I finally got matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
    0&0&0&0&0&\frac{5}{2}\\
    0&0&0&0&\frac{3}{2}&0\\
    0&0&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\
     0&0&-\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0\\
    0&-\frac{3}{2}&0&0&0&0\\
    -\frac{5}{2}&0&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}

Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Yes you are right. The dimension of the Hilbert space is $2\frac{5}{2}+1=6$. Thus an operator has to be represented by a $6\times6$ matrix. As one has 
$$J_{z}|5/2, m)=m|5/2, m)$$
With $m\in\{-5/2, -3/2, ..., 5/2\}$ one may write a Hilbert Schmidt decomposition of $J_{z}$ as
$$J_{z}=\sum_{m=-5/2}^{5/2}m|5/2, m)(5/2, m|$$
Than it is a matter of choosing an orthonormal basis. You have chosen just a standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{6}$.